# First order differential equation with variable separable

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Need help with this differential equation: 
$$\sqrt{3+y^2}dx-xdy=x^2dy$$ I began with variable separable method. So, already had done this:$$\sqrt{3+y^2}dx=(x^2+x)dy$$
$$\frac{dx}{x^2+x}=\frac{dy}{\sqrt{3+y^2}}$$
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+x}=\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{3+y^2}}$$
Now I should solve that two integrals, but have some trouble with them and need your help. Also, I need help, explanation how to draw phase portrait for this equation, maybe some useful material about that?

Comment: But your equation is given by $$\sqrt{3+y^2}=xy'(x)+x^2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that was a typo. already corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Hint.

Use

$$
\frac{1}{x^2+x} = \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x+1}
$$

$$
\frac{dy}{\sqrt{a+y^2}} = \frac{d\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{a}}\right)}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt a}\right)^2}}
$$

Comment: ok, thank you. What about phase portrait to this equation?

Comment: You can use Wolfram. See this example https://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427elrmoum15af